# how would I convert the sqrt(x2 − x1)^2 (y2 − y1)^2 to proper java code

Tags: sum, pow, square-root

How would I convert the equation for the distance between two points:

```
sqrt((x2 − x1)^2 + (y2 − y1)^2)
```

into proper Java code?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The `sqrt` is probably supposed to surround both of the terms.

Comment: Eh, non. `hypot(x2 - x2, y2 - y1)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.pow` and `Math.sqrt` of package `java.lang.Math`